# Change canvas size in xmgrace (not dragging)

Tags: xmgrace

I am trying to plot something on xmgrace, but I encountered a problem when I modified the size of the axis label and tick label font: the size of the fonts is too big and it pushes the labels out of the page, so that when I try to print i get the following error:

```
[Error] Output is truncated - tune device dimensions
```

The following picture is an example of the problem (the y axis label is slightly out of the page):

[image]

Now, to solve this I could double-click on the black squares on the corners of the canvas (*red circle in the picture*) and drag the canvas' border to make the label fit. But this is not precise enough because it has to be done manually.

How can I change the canvas dimensions more precisely, i.e. from keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the dimensions of the plot by clicking

```
Plot > Graph Appearance
```

The "Viewport" settings control the start and end positions of the x and y axes relative to the edges of the canvas.

For example, to avoid your y axis label being cut off, increase `Xmin`by a small amount (default value is 0.15, try changing it to 0.2). You might also want to change `Xmax` by the same increment in order to preserve your graph's aspect ratio.